# Undefined property: stdClass: - What is wrong?

Tags: php

I get some data externally but gets this error because the variable is "empty":

> Undefined property: stdClass::$summary in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/jobportal/functions.php on line 68

I have tried to build a function to help me:

```
$summary = convert_empty($user->summary);

function convert_empty($data) {
    if(isset($data)) {  
        return $data;
    } else {
        return ".";
    }
}
```

But the error is still there. I have tried `isset`, `empty`, and `defined`. I think I miss another point here - since none of it is working.

Comment: It's this part that's causing the error: `$user->summary` so the function won't help, can we see how `$user` is defined?

Comment: $summary = convert_empty($user->summary); is giving the error.

I am not sure what to send you. I take data from Linkedins API - where data is from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

The data is something like:
stdClass Object
(
    [emailAddress] => xxxx
    [firstName] => xxx
...

And summary is not a part of it :(

Comment: Ok, no problem, see Syscall's answer, as it solves the problem in the more generic way. for information, PHP functions like `is_object` and `property_exists` would allow you to be more specific about what is `$user` and its properties

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not in your function, but how you call it. The error is that you're trying to access `->summary` but doesn't exists. You could use something like this:

```
$summary = convert_empty($user, 'summary');

function convert_empty($data, $key) {
    if (isset($data->$key)) 
       return $data->$key;
    return ".";
}
```

Note that you should also test if `$data` is an object too.

```
    if (is_object($data) && isset($data->$key)) { ... }
```

---

Or, without a function using conditional ternary operator :

```
$summary = isset($user->summary) ? $user->summary : '.';
```

---

**EDIT** for a deeper use :

```
convert_empty($user, 'positions', 'values', $i, 'title');

function convert_empty($obj) {
    $error = '.';
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args); // remove $obj
    $ref = $obj ;
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if (is_array($ref)) {
            if (!isset($ref[$arg])) return $error ;
            $ref = $ref[$arg] ;
        }
        elseif (is_object($ref)) {
            if (!isset($ref->$arg)) return $error ;
            $ref = $ref->$arg ;
        }
    }
    return $ref ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What do I do with the first solution if I need to go deeper?
Like: $user->positions->values[$i]->title

Comment: @Rmadsen A bit more complicated. You could use `convert_empty($user, 'positions', 'values', $i, 'title');`, then, in the function, loop around `func_get_args()`, keep a reference of the "last" element, check if it is an array or an object, and return it or stop if the element is not found.

Answer (score 2):

That means that the object $user doesn't have a summary member variable defined.

```
$summary = isset($user->summary) ? convert_empty($user->summary) : NULL;
```

Or

```
$summary = isset($user->summary) ? convert_empty(isset($user->summary) ? $user->summary : NULL);
```

Now you won't see the warning and $summary will be set to NULL, assuming that you're expecting $summary to be NULL in this situation in which $user->summary is undefined.

The second one allows your convert_empty to figure it out.